# How to access mappings with web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js

My contract stores data in a mapping like the following:

```
mapping(address => uint256) public data_stores;
```

How can I view the data on a front end with web3js?

I have managed to view a uint256 like the below example.

```
uint256 public tester
```

the javascript

```
myContract.tester.call(function(err,res)
{
  console.log(res)
});
```

If I try the above for the mapping I get an error stating I have an invalid number of arguments for the solidity function.  (I am assuming this is because I did not pass in an address for the mapping).

Answer (score 1):

The public variables can be accessed as follows:-

```
 myContract.tester.call()
    .(then(function(tester) {
          console.log("Tester", tester);
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
          console.error("problem getting tester", err);
 });
```

In the case of mapping you have to create a `get` function in your contract and then call that function from your js

```
function getValueAtMapping(address userAddress)  public  constant  returns(uint value) {
      return data_stores[userAddress];
}
```

Then call the above function in your js by passing the address similar to above.

```
   myContract.getValueAtMapping.call(userAddress)
    .(then(function(tester) {
          console.log("Tester", tester);
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
          console.error("problem getting tester", err);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mapping` is `public` which means it gets a "free" getter that relieves the contract developer of the burden of writing it out. If it was written out (and we ignore the name conflict), it would look like this:

```
function data_stores(address index) public view returns(uint) {
  return data_stores[index];
}
```

As @Soham says, pass the address in so it knows which of the mapped `uint` values to return.

Borrowed from Soham (looks right to me ;-)

```
myContract.data_stores.call(address,function(err,res) {
  console.log(res)
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You shall pass address to mapping `data_stores` to retrieve `uint256` element stored in a mapping.

It is like a key value pair and you shall pass a key to get a value.

`myContract.data_stores.call(address,function(err,res)
{
  console.log(res)
});`